# What exactly makes a person's voice differ from other's?

Tags: voice, speech, phonetics

What are the characteristics of a voice that make it different from other voice, in terms of properties of the sound wave ?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is very generic:

- **Frequency**: Changes in wave frequency relate to pitch/intonation
- **Amplitude**: Changes in wave amplitude relate to stress and pronunciation

But that is pretty much the answer to every other "*What are the characteristics of X that make it different from other X'es, in terms of properties of the sound wave?*"

The more interesting aspects are the harmonies and resonances, or **formants**. The formants are formed by chamber and tube resonances, which is what makes us able to distinguish the different vowels. But the formant "weight" or tendency of a voice is also what makes it very characteristic (and the main difference between male and female, along with pitch) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant)).

Check out this [interactive formant/vowel app](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415201847/https://auditoryneuroscience.com/topics/two-formant-artificial-vowels)

In terms of wave properties formants describe how multiple frequences relate and work together.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes one voice sound different from another is the same thing that makes a trumpet sound different from a tuba: the different size and shape of the instrument. That produces a dramatically different sound wave. You’ll get a different frequency spectrum from each voice. Imagine a trumpet, a slightly bigger trumpet, a slightly longer trumpet, and so on for 7 billion more trumpets until you get to a tuba. Every one of them will make the spectrum on an EQ light up slightly differently.